# HTML div doesn't remain visible even after updating the CSS display tag to block after a button click in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to build a Google Chrome extension which consists of a button in the popup window.

Upon clicking this button I want a certain HMTL div (a table in my case) for which the initial CSS display tag is "none" to be set to "block" so that the div is made visible in the popup window. In my popup.js file, I have used an event listener to handle this button click.

The problem am facing is that once I click the button the div which was made visible appears and gets hidden the very next moment. It doesn't stay visible and looks like the initial "display: none" setting is taking over again. Please find my code below and help me resolve this issue.

Manifest.json :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Google Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "64": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

Popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style type="text/css">

      body {        
        margin: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

      #container {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      #displayTable {
        display: none;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }      
      #myTable td, #myTable th {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 8px;
      }
      #myTable th {
        background-color: #ddd;
      }
    </style>

     <script src="popup.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Google Chrome Extension</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <form>
        Provide input:<br>
        <input type="text" id="inputText" maxlength="7"><br>
        <button id="shoot">Shoot</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="displayTable">
      <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
          <td>Column1</td>
          <td>Column2</td>
          <td>Column3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id = "col1"></td>
          <td id = "col2"></td>
          <td id = "col3"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var btn = document.getElementById('shoot');
  btn.addEventListener('click', getTable);
});

function getTable() {
  var col1 = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  var col2 = 0;
  var col3 = 0;
  document.getElementById('col1').innerHTML = col1;
  document.getElementById('col2').innerHTML = col2;
  document.getElementById('col3').innerHTML = col3;
  document.getElementById('displayTable').style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: Probably the form is submitting and your page is reloading, which resets the initial JS and CSS property display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the button is in a form, it is submitting the form and reloading popup.html. The simplest thing is just change your form to a div.

If you need to keep it a form, you need to prevent the form from submitting, so modify your code to:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var btn = document.getElementById('shoot');
    btn.addEventListener('click', getTable);
    var formElement = document.querySelector('form');
    formElement.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Although the latter solution didn't seem to work, the simple solution of changing the form to div fixed the issue for me.